# C# Process Start Stuck

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple TCP Server application,
when the program gets the request it will call an exe file to do something.
The application works fine on my PC.

But when I run on another PC the thread will stuck because it stuck in process start, so I checked the task manager whether the exe file did run. and it really work.

I have no idea how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
string path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "FileTransferTool\\FileTransfer.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

process.Start();  // the thread stuck here
```

I print out the message, it shows

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):

The system cannot find the file specified at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startIn
fo) 
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()  at ClassPackage.DsUploadFiletoNC.Start(Object[] param)

Comment: Could be access issue that the other PC don't have access in the shared folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding another process to call cmd.exe on the top of the main program, the code shown as below :

And the program will run as Administrator, but I don't know why

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        string path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";

        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        //process.StartInfo.FileName = "FileTransferTool\\circle.txt";

        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        //process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.Start();

        using (TCPServer server = new TCPServer())
        {
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Socket Server Start...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```